# A certain complete intersection family

Tags: algebraic-geometry, diophantine-equations

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic zero.
Given integers $2 \leq s \leq r < n$, define the variety $X_n$ in $P_K^n$ with coordinates $y_0, \cdots, y_n$  and  $K=k(u_0, \cdots, u_n)$ ( where $u_i$'s are independent transcendental vairables)  by the folloing $n-r$ equatuions:

$$ f_{i-r}(y_0, y_1, \cdots, y_n)=
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 & 1 \\ 
u_0& u_1& \cdots & u_r & u_i\\
\vdots & \vdots & \cdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
u_0^r & u_1^r & \cdots & u_r^r& u_i^r\\
y_0^s &  y_1^s & \cdots & y_r^s & y_i^s
\end{vmatrix} =0, \  (r+1 \leq i \leq n).
$$

It is easy to see that for fixed $r$,  $s$, and  $n  > (sr + 1)/(s−1)$,  $X_n$ is a smooth complete intersection variety of general type with $\dim(X_n)=r$.
For a set of pairwise distinct elements  $b=\{b_0, b_1, \cdots, b_n\}$ in $k$, letting $u_i=b_i$, one can get  $ X_{b, n}$ a smooth variety defined over $k$.

Question: Is it possible to show that $X_{b, n}$ is a Geometric Mordellic variety, i.e., $X_{b, n}$  does not contain subvarieties which are not of general type over $\bar{k}$ the algebraic closure of $k$?